# How do I detect Individual Wired Headphones?

Tags: android, ios, networking, headphones

I am trying to develop a system where I can figure out that how much amount of time I have used one particular Headphone on a device (let's say for a system that shows that how much an individual device has been used for).

Even after searching on the net a lot, I still cannot find if there's a way to differentiate between individual wired headphones. Is it because they do not have a device identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because they don't have any way of talking to the device.  The phone jack and headphones are extremely dumb.  The tech dates back to the 70s or earlier.  No information is exchanged, it just puts out an audio signal to whatever is attached.  No handshaking, no identification.